Summarize Large Dataset By Count of Specific Values from Column A into Additional Columns
I have two datasets, Person_Info and Visit_Info.
Person_Info:



Person_ID
Home_City




1
New_York


2
New_York


3
Miami


4
Chicago



Visit_Info:



Person_ID
Visit_City




1
New_York


2
Miami


2
Miami


2
Miami


3
Miami


3
Chicago


4
Chicago



I am looking to create a matrix in PySpark that calculates the total number of people by Home_City and finds a count of how many distinct other cities they visited. I do not want to know how many times, just that they went at least once.



Home_City
Total_People
New_York
Miami
Chicago




New_York
2
1
1
0


Miami
1
0
1
1


Chicago
1
0
0
1



In the above example, you can see Person_ID 2 visited Miami 3 times, but I only want to count that as 1.
I can build the first two columns:
df = df_person_info \
    .groupBy('Home_City') \
    .agg( \
        F.count('Person_ID').alias('Total_People'), \
        F.expr('collect_list(Person_ID)').alias('List_IDs')\
    )

That gives me a column of the Home_City, Total_People in that city and a list of all the People_IDs in that home city.
I am struggling to expand it to "fill in the blanks". I know how to do it "old school" via multiple for-loops in Python and look up the same data over and over again.
With hundreds of Cities, the job is taking extremely long to complete and I am getting a:

java.lang.StackOverflowError when trying to save the dataframe.


looks you can drop_duplicates and then do crosstab: df_visit_info.join(df_person_info,"Person_ID").drop_duplicates(["Visit_City","Home_City"]).crosstab("Home_City","Visit_City").

As mentioned in the comments by @lihao you can use crosstab for the "second part" of your solution as follows:
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

person_data = [(1, "New_York"), (2, "New_York"), (3, "Miami"), (4, "Chicago")]
df_person_info = spark.createDataFrame(person_data, ["Person_ID", "Home_City"])

visit_data = [(1, "New_York"), (2, "Miami"), (2, "Miami"), (2, "Miami"), (3, "Miami"), (3, "Chicago"), (4, "Chicago")]
df_visit_info = spark.createDataFrame(visit_data, ["Person_ID", "Visit_City"])

total_people_df = df_person_info.groupBy("Home_City").agg(
    F.countDistinct("Person_ID").alias("Total_People")
)

crosstab_df = (
    df_person_info.join(df_visit_info.dropDuplicates(), "Person_ID")
    .crosstab("Home_City", "Visit_City")
    .withColumnRenamed("Home_City_Visit_City", "Home_City")
)

df = total_people_df.join(crosstab_df, "Home_City")

df.show()

# +---------+------------+-------+-----+--------+
# |Home_City|Total_People|Chicago|Miami|New_York|
# +---------+------------+-------+-----+--------+
# | New_York|           2|      0|    1|       1|
# |  Chicago|           1|      1|    0|       0|
# |    Miami|           1|      1|    1|       0|
# +---------+------------+-------+-----+--------+

